# I accidentally formatted my hard disk when installing Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I was planning to shift from Windows 10 to Ubuntu.
Usually when you install new version of Windows, you do that in C:/ drive.(100GB) The other drives (d:/ and e:/) about 350GB are are not touched.

So when I tried to install Ubuntu.. I did guess a question of formatting the disk. But little did I know that the whole Hard drive will be formatted.
After installing Ubuntu, all my data from d:/ and e:/ are also erased.
Somebody please help me out. :( :(

Comment: Rule 1) Do not write to the disk until you have recovered your files. I accidentally installed Lubuntu Live, overwriting a 4TB disk filled with all my old movies. The only thing I could find to recover the files that really worked was EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard. Unfortunately it is a Windows program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `testdisk` to recover lost Partitions/Partition Tables.
install it using `sudo apt-get install testdisk`.

check the guide how to recover them [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/)

Other guide: [here](https://www.tecmint.com/recover-deleted-files-using-testdisk-in-linux/)

Note: that guide is for recovering the files inside it.
not the OS.